# Changing data in sheet when clicking on List Box

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a ListBox ActiveX on Excel. I would like to put different data on the sheet according to what is selected on the listbox. For instance now "Semaine 48" is selected and the data is 111 and 222.

However what i want is not to set the data with vba code but that when the user has selected "Semaine 47" and changes for instance 111 in something else, the change is saved and when the user closes and then opens again the file, the data is still changed (and not 111)

Could you please help?

[image]

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Dim tableau(1, 2) As String 
tableau(0, 0) = "1"
tableau(1, 0) = "2"

tableau(0, 1) = "11"
tableau(1, 1) = "22"

tableau(0, 2) = "111"
tableau(1, 2) = "222"

Dim I As Integer
I = ListBox1.ListIndex

Select Case (I)
  Case Is = 0
    Range("A11") = tableau(0, 0)
Range("B11") = tableau(1, 0)

  Case Is = 1
    Range("A11") = tableau(0, 1)
Range("B11") = tableau(1, 1)

  Case Is = 2
    Range("A11") = tableau(0, 2)
Range("B11") = tableau(1, 2)

End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use the `worksheetchange`-event to change the sourcevalue acording to the selection of your listbox... however... its impossible if the values are from vba itself... (ok, it is possible, but you dont want that)

Comment: What is the best practice for that?  If i want that the user can have different values according to the selection of the listbox, and that the changes he makes are registered? Thank you

Comment: Having the data in sheet2... then the selected item# of the list is rhe row (+1) of sheet2... having an `worksheetchange`-event which will put changes in A11/B11 to the acording cells in sheet2... you just need to deactivate it for the time your list Puts data in A11/B11... i'll write a short  example as soon as i'm back home...

Answer (score 0):

OK, asuming (like said in comments) `sheet2` looks like that:

```
  |    A    |    B    |
1 | item1a  | item1b  |
2 | item2a  | item2b  |
3 | item3a  | item3b  |
4 | item4a  | item4b  |
...
```

Then in Module:

```
Option Explicit 'You don't need that, but i recommend it

Public iLBItem As Long 'this is needed here (not in a sub)
```

Change your Listbox-code to:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click() 'still, i recommend using ListBox1_Change()
  Dim i As Integer
  iLBItem = 0
  i = ListBox1.ListIndex + 1
  Sheet1.Cells(11, 1).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(11, 2).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value
  iLBItem = i
End Sub
```

It does the same like your code, but picks the values from sheet2.

Add in the sheet where your listbox is present:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If iLBItem Then
    If Target.Address = "$A$11" Then Sheet2.Cells(iLBItem, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(11, 1).Value
    If Target.Address = "$B$11" Then Sheet2.Cells(iLBItem, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(11, 2).Value
  End If
End Sub
```

Whenever something is changed in the sheet, it checks for `iLBItem` to be `<> 0` (`0` counts as false / `>0` counts as true => just `If iLBItem Then` will work). If thats true it will check for the address of the change `Target.Address`. Having `$A$11` and `$B$11` here it will simply put the values of this sheet to the row saved in `iLBItem` in sheet2.

If you still have any questions, just write a comment. :)

Comment: Thank you Dirk for your message. But is it possible to use only one sheet and to have the cells value changing in this sheet when I click on the items of the list? What is most important is that the cells value will be changed by the user, and I want that when i close the file and re open it we still have these values. It's just like having 3 sheets in one basically. Thank you

Comment: you could change the `Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value` to `Sheet1.Cells(i + 100, 1).Value` to set the source-table to thefirstsheet (starting with row 101). However, after opening the workbook your listbox normally doesn't have a selection, which makes it impossible to know what data is linked... still you could also change `iLBItem` also to a cell like `Sheet1.Cells(100, 1).Value` having `A100` as ref for your `Worksheet_SelectionChange`